# How to create a Firebase Audience to ask for an App Store Review/Rating

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I want to create a Firebase Audience to ask to rate/review my app.

The condition I would like to have for a user to fit into the above audience is: a user who has opened the app at least 10 times, over the course of 3 distinct days.

Is it possible to create an audience with this condition?

I am open to suggestions to change/improve the condition. Or even a completely different condition that will achieve the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom audience, choose events as condition and pick `session_start`. 
Than you can choose additional options like the number of session and period. 
[image]

This does not guarantee you 3 distinct days though. But by default Firebase will only count a new session every 30min. So most of those users have had their session over 3 days anyways. Firebase also gives you a preview of the audience size. So you can easily check how many users would be in that audience with a period of e.g. one day.

In general i would recommend asking users for rating who had a positive experience within your app. Completing certain action etc. and use that event for the audience.